# Does JPA use entity equals for comparison in queries

Tags: hibernate, jpa

If I do a comparison between two objects in a JPA query. Ex

```
select user.id where user = :user
```

Does JPA use the equals method on the User class to compare the two or does it use something like PK?

Answer (score 2):

Most probably the `@Id` is used. Otherwise the provider would need to instantiate at least some of the users in the table for a comparison, which could be very very expensive.

You can try logging the generated SQL to be sure.

Comment: Most probably? is it up to the implementation?

Comment: I could not find anything about it in the spec, so it must be the responsibility of the persistence provider.

Answer (score 1):

`equals()` is something that is not so easy to translate to a SQL standard `WHERE` clause and also that no query reads actually the code (of `equals()`). This means, it uses simply the PK for that. Also you could check the SQL queries executed by your JPA implementation (hibernate) and you will see that. Although that is not part of the specification, you could think of the situation, when you count 1 mln entities with a certain condition: it would be an overkill to extract all rows and to call `equals()` on them.